# How do playthroughs work in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been looking around a lot, asking friends etc. about how the playthrough system specifically works in Borderlands 2 I am completely new to the franchise but have a decent idea of how things work.

I simply ask what specifically happens/changes in each playthrough , such as if gear will level up with you, at what points gear levels to you and so on. I may end up asking a few questions too. (Don't take it to heart about your skill at explaining things, I'm a slow learner :P).

P.S Bear in mind this is the Handsome Collection, playing on PS4. I will have all DLCs.

Comment: Gear does not level with you after it drops. The game will drop gear that matches your level. You'll be able to find higher level gear in higher difficulties also. FYI: It's best to just ask the questions that you have, like in a bullet format or numbered format.

Answer (score 0):

On each higher level you play the game the enemies will be harder. Some enemy types just appear on the higher levels though. You will need to play the game 3 times. After that you can go to digistruct peak to make your so called overpower runs. Each run takes around 30-120 minutes and will award you with the next higher overpower rank - if you pass it. Each overpower run will be harder, longer, with more enemies and enemietypes in more arenas.

The main goal is to get better stuff each playthrough. Sometimes you need to grind some enemies to get a special loot (if you like) or just to get some xp to get to the next level.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: This does help a great help a great deal with the OP levels. Which time is the best for me to begin farming for legendaries in play through terms to make sure I don't have to keep farming again for weapons to stay at my level? Nonetheless, thank you for your answer

Comment: Well I normally farmed the bosses for some time if they have a loot which is good. Not every boss has a weapon which is worth to farm. But I normally farm the end boss for a weapon (pumpgun) and after the end boss a guy in a radio station for a shield. Then go on in the next play through. In OP you NEED to farm after every run. At the first 2-4 levels it's ok to farm all 2 levels. But at 5-8 the dmg of your weapon is nearly doubled in some cases.

Comment: Ah thank you for this. I wasn't sure about which time to farm so I wouldn't have to do it for rare guns like shredifier, skullmasher etc for them to stay at around my level

Comment: Well the level during the first playthrough's isn't that important. I've played with a lvl 35 unique pumpgun while I'm level 55 and was faster than a friend of mine with his lvl 55 gun. The special ability is what counts. Later on in the OP runs everything should be on the right OP level. Trick: if you have the christmas DLC, you can farm the snowman boss and go to the train afterwards. He is fast to kill and the train can give you EVERY weapon. Even uniques from other bosses. This is a great thing. Normally I farm him 1 hour and my whole equipment is on a new stage.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't know about that snowman boss.

Comment: @PaKaPoW14 it's the best boss in the gam (my opinion). By the way you can also farm tongue marks if you have the tongue dlc to buy the legendary handgun at the yellow box. It's one of the best handguns for farming the snowman.

Comment: Oh do you mean the Unkempt Harold?

Comment: Yes! I just didn't get on the name. Best version in my eyes is the double unkept. Not good for your ammunition but fast for the snow man. Great in combination with the bee. 1 minute for a run + 1 minute reload and looting = 30 runs/hour. But it depends S you need some time to get to the snowman.

Comment: Which DLC is it?

Comment: It depends what you mean. The torgue marks for the unkept harold can be achieved in `Mr. Torgue’s Campaign of Carnage` in `Pyro Pete's Bar` in `The Beatdown` (see_ http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Pyro_Pete's_Bar). The snowman can be found in `Headhunter 3: Mercenary Day`, the snowman is now as `Mister Tinder Snowflake` but his name changes due to many kills over the time. :-) (see here: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/How_Marcus_Saved_Mercenary_Day and here: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Tinder_Snowflake and the loot here: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mtk96e7gZpI/hqdefault.jpg)